# Multiple colormaps using bar(z,'stacked')

Tags: matlab

I have read the article recommended by a post on another `colormap` thread http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101346 and I understand the concept. I am having trouble understanding the values of `CDATA` when using the `bar(z,'stacked')` function.

I have one figure with a major axis plotted using `cmap`, and I have created and positioned a new axis for the bar chart and I want it to use `cmap2`.

For example, my code includes:

```
maps = colormap([cmap;cmap2]);
bH = bar(z,'stacked');
```

Where z = 25x10 (annual data for 10 years over 25 sites)

Now when I look at the `CDATA`

`get(bH,'CDATA')` A cell array is returned of size 1x10 with each cell containing the string 'scaled'.

Now if I look at the `CDATA` of each of the children

```
childH = get(bH,'children');
get(childH{i},'CDATA')
```

A matrix of size 25x10 is returned with every value equal.

e.g. `childH{i}`'s `CDATA` is a matrix of size 25x10 having all values `= i`

So how can I scale these to map to my `colormap` since
from the documentation above I need to perform:

```
m = size(colormap,1);   % Number of colors in the current colormap
Data = get(H,'CData')   % Where H is a handle to a surface or patch object
cmin = min(CData(:));   % Minimum color value
cmax = max(CData(:));   % Maximum color value
idx = min(m,round((m-1)*(CData-cmin)/(cmax-cmin))+1);
```

`idx` becomes `min(m,nan)` which is always `m`?

I really need help understanding this.

Am I missing something or is this function a special case?

Comment: Special case, kind of: `bar` returns a handle to a `barseries` rather than a primitive graphics object like `surface` or `patch`, thus `bH` doesn't have a `CData` property (although your results imply it _does_ have an undocumented `CDataMapping` property). You're right that you need to deal with its children which are the actual `patch` objects - I don't have Matlab to hand to work out an actual answer, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure that `cmap2` has exactly the number of colors that you want to use, then get the barseries object to map into it directly. Something like:

```
childH = get(bH, 'children');
for a = 1:numel(childH)
   C = get(childH{a}, 'FaceVertexCData');
   C(:) = a+size(cmap, 1);
   set(childH{a}, 'FaceVertexCData', C, 'CDataMapping', 'direct');
end
```

Comment: that will do it. i now need to read up a little about that FaceVertexCData property. thanks a lot